# How to remove color highlight from match() function from Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to have second color highlight in Vim,
The simply way to do is use the `:match`, `:2match`, or `:3match` commands:

```
:match TODO /pattern/
```

`TODO` is the highlight group; pattern will be highlighted like `':/'`.

I have hard time to figure out how to remove the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can undo a `:match TODO /pattern/` command with `:match none`, or just `:match`. Same for the other `:2match` and `:3match` variants.

The generic `matchdelete()` function typically is used in scripts to undo a match added via `:matchadd()`. As you use these commands interactively (for a limited set of matches), I would not advise that you switch to them.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a command for this as far as I know, but you can use the [`clearmatches()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#clearmatches%28%29) and [`matchdelete()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchdelete%28%29) functions.

`clearmatches()` will remove *all* matches:

```
:call clearmatches()
```

And `matchdelete()` to remove a specific match instance; you can get the ID from `getmatches()`:

```
:for m in filter(getmatches(), { i, v -> l:v.group is? 'TODO' })
:  call matchdelete(m.id)
:endfor
```

You can also filter matches on e.g. the matching pattern with the `pattern` key. An `:Unmatch` command might look like:

```
command! -nargs=1 Unmatch
    \  for m in filter(getmatches(), { i, v -> l:v.group is? <q-args> })
    \|     call matchdelete(m.id)
    \| endfor
```